# What should WWW-Authenticate contains for a 401 response espeically for a REST API?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-status-code-401

If the credential is incorrect or invalid, and if I choose to go with 401, what should the `WWW-Authenticate` header value be? What should the realm be, especially for REST API?

Most examples I see are `WWW-Authenticate: realm="Company website" location="...."` but this is more like for browser client.

Answer (score 1):

WWW-Authenticate response header includes "challenge" and what the challenge includes is depends on the authentication scheme you use.

If you use Basic Authentication, the challenge includes only a string "Basic" and a realm, such as:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="WallyWorld"
```

And if you use Digest Authentication, it should includes a string "Digest" and many fields, such as:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest
             realm="testrealm@host.com",
             qop="auth,auth-int",
             nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093",
             opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"
```

See [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) for HTTP Authentication schemes and [RFC 2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) for Basic and Digest Authentication.